# Are there any mathematical methods which can analogize a discrete 2D matrix into a function (describing the continuous surface)?

Tags: linear-algebra, surfaces

It's a very naive and ignorant question, but let's say if we have a 2D matrix (with high dimensionality), are there any methods using which we could create a continuous surface (i.e. described by a function) out of that matrix?

What I want to know is if there exist any mathematical methods through which one can convert a digital image (grey scale), which is basically a large 2D matrix, to an analog mathematical representation in terms of a 2-variable function, i.e. given the x, y values, the function should be able to give us the intensity of the image for any real valued x and y.
Maybe, in a way, what the method should be doing is to "fill" with continuous values the discrete gaps between the elements of the 2D matrix.

Comment: There are many such ways. In fact there are so many ways to do it so it is difficult to know where to start.

Comment: It is basically a problem of interpolating a set of points $(x,y,f(x,y))$ isn't it.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst
I honestly don't have much idea but yeah what you are saying seems to make a bit of a sense to me. 
However, do you know any online tools which could allow to generate such a f(x,y) from an image?

Comment: I'd definitely do it in R
https://cran.r-project.org/
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/
(R studio is like a gui for R, definitely get it, you'll be able to suss it out from there, happy to answer qs though).

I've found a package you could use for this, it mentions images too which is a stroke of luck:
https://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/interp.surface.html

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst 
Thanks a lot!